# JNI for dummies

Tags: java-native-interface

I have just started reading up on the JNI and guy from the C++ side of our project has just pointed me towards 2 files,  the Java Interface and the DLL file.
With the DLL in hand do I need to have any other knowledge of what is going on on the C++ side. Do I now just put the DLL in the class path and access it via the Java interface he has given me? He created a header file using the Java interface and this is included in the .cpp file.  From that I assume the DLL was generated.

The following is some of the code I have

```
    System.loadLibrary("PredictionService");
    JNIPrediction predictor = new JNIPrediction();
    predictor.getPredictions("test");
```

I don't get any errors so does this mean it is loading the DLL successfully and calling the getPredictions() method inside the DLL?
Basically I was needing to know is this how you use JNI typically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'Java Interface File' is not a commonly defined term.  You need at least a C header file or some documentation to indicate how the functions in your DLL need to be called.  The only information you're likely to get from the DLL itself is the names of the available methods.

While it is possible to embed debug information in the DLL which describes the DLL method signatures, it's not likely that you have such in your DLL, and you need additional tools to be able to make use of it.